# Internet Explorer 11 automation error

Tags: vba

I am having a problem when using vba from excel to navigate on multiple pages. I have used the code on ie8 and ie9 without any problems, but in ie11, when i navigate to another url the ie.locationurl and ie.document still refer to the previous url. I noticed this only happens with php websites. I am interested in finding a way to solve this. Any help appreciated.

*Here is some example code with a php website:*

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With ie
.navigate "https://www.facebook.com/" 'php website
.Visible = True
Do While ie.Busy
Loop
Do While ie.readyState <> 4
Loop

.navigate "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
.Visible = True

Debug.Print ie.locationurl

Do While ie.Busy
Loop
Do While ie.readyState <> 4
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

*And here is one that works but doesn't have a php website:*

```
Sub test2()
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With ie
.navigate "http://www.break.com/" 'non php website
.Visible = True
Do While ie.Busy
Loop
Do While ie.readyState <> 4
Loop

.navigate "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"
.Visible = True

Debug.Print ie.locationurl

Do While ie.Busy
Loop
Do While ie.readyState <> 4
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting the [LocationURL property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before you've allowed the page to load.

```
Sub test()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.facebook.com/" 'php website

        Debug.Print "1." & .locationurl
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Debug.Print "2." & ie.locationurl

        .navigate "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"

        Debug.Print "3." & .locationurl
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Debug.Print "4." & .locationurl

    End With
End Sub
```

Results from the VBE's Immediate window:

```
test
1.
2.https://www.facebook.com/
3.https://www.facebook.com/
4.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page
```

I've paired up the `ie.Busy` and `ie.readyState` checks and threw `DoEvents` into the loop to allow some processing to happen while the page loads. You were not taking full advantage of the parent `ie` object references in the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) so I chopped off a few unnecessary `ie` references within the block.

As the Internet Explorer version is pertinent to this question, this is the version that the code was run on.

[image: Internet Explorer 11]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did you run this on internet explorer 11, cause I just did and it still shows the same error:( The process stops on the last loop where ie keeps being .busy.

Comment: Yes, it was IE11 version 11.0.960.18015, update version 11.0.23 (see above).

Comment: Ok. I can't figure out what the problem is because this also happened on other computers at work that also had ie11. I have the latest update 11.0.10240.16431.  I noticed that if I run the code with F8 it works.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the update version is 11.0.22 (KB3078071)